# Initializing static member from member function of null object

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I have below code in c++/cli.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

ref class Test
{
public:
    void SetI(int k)
    {
        i = k;
    }
private:
    static int i = 0;
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Test ^obj = nullptr;
    obj->SetI(10);

    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

in main eventhough obj is nullptr and called SetI, it is working without any crash.
If varibale i of Test becomes member variable, SetI called on nullptr crashed.
What could be the reason.

Comment: C++/CLI does not have the C# feature that promises you get an NRE at the call site.  It is UB like it is in native C++.  It does not crash since you don't dereference *this*, the variable is static.  And of course does when it is not static.

Answer (score 0):

You mean regular member variable instead of static member ?

The memory for a **static** member is always reserved. It lives elsewhere and not in the memory location of any created object. Thats the reason it can be set with a null class.

A regular member lives within the memory of a created object and if no such object exists you get a segfault.